# javascript, Error while using class from a module : Cannot access class before initialization

Tags: javascript, class, module, initialization, export

I have a module file (modules.js). In addtion, script.js. I want to define a class in modules.js and then using that in script.js. I get this error in console:
'Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'myClass' before initialization'.
How can I fix it?

modules.js:

```
export class myClass{
  constructor(name){
    this.name=name;
  }
  printHello(){
    console.log("Hello");
  }
}
```

script.js:

```
import { myClass} from "./modules.js";
var myObject=new myClass("Jacky");
myObject.printHello();
```

Comment: could you give us the code of HTML where you import two scripts?